# How to make CSS hexagon honeycomb structur

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to make this following structure of honeycomb with hexagon, in a 3-4-3 and 2-3-2 structure. Want to make it responsive when the screen size decrease after a certain width it will change it structure from 3-4-3 to 2-3-2.

[image]

Something like this, can anyone help me with following structure, any help would be very much appriciated.

I tried using flex wrap but the hexagon align just below one another.

Comment: Please provide code you worked/done to solve the issue then we can help. We simply cant provide the code for you.

Comment: Check this pan from webtiki. you can get idea/help. https://codepen.io/web-tiki/pen/NzYBYV

Comment: This could help aswell https://css-tricks.com/hexagons-and-beyond-flexible-responsive-grid-patterns-sans-media-queries/